# Sending some data from jQuery, calling function that is in PHP by setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I want to use $.post to call a function which is in PHP, but each time I try, it only executes once:

jQuery:

```
function sth()
{
    $.post('index.php', { on:'1' }, function(data){});
}
setInterval(sth, 1000);
```

PHP:

```
function sthElse()
{
    // Some Code
}

if($_POST['on'])
{
    sthElse();
}
```

Comment: How exactly did you deduce that it triggered only once? Can you try adding a line `console.log('Sending post query')` to the start of `sth()`, before the `$.post`, and tell us what you see on the console output?

Comment: no dear, it executes every 1 second, but sthElse executes once! because after sending and inside sth() I wrote alert('blabla'); and every 1 second it executes correctly!

Comment: Ok, so you deduced it from the server side. What does `sthElse` do that makes you think it happens only once?

Comment: because when I marked the string that was echoed out, it doesn't get out of state of marking, but as I know when I select(mark) it, it must deselect it when it recall the function! Am I right?

Comment: if($_POST['on'])
 sthElse();
else
 sthElse();     and also in this statement only else works not if one!

Comment: Just a suggestion, using `alert` is blocking in nature, prefer using `console.log` instead and keep the console of the browser open. This will also help to see if any other error was thrown

Comment: Try this, edit your post call back to this `function(data){console.log(data);}` . And in your `function sthElse()` echo a simple hello. And watch the browser console with this page open

Comment: thanks but same result :(  it returns complete page!

Comment: What do you see? Can you edit your post and provide the console output that you see on your browser? I've put everything together in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in adding the return result to your HTML. Here's how you do that

Have a parent div where you can keep appending your list of results to

HTML:

```
<div id="listOfReturns"></div>
```

In the JS, you should slice by index, or split by separator, your return string data, to extract the part you want and then append it as a div to the above div

JS:

```
SEPARATOR= "||";

function sth()
{
    console.log('Sending post');
    $.post('index.php', { on:'1' }, function(data){
       console.log('Received data: '+data);
       //Consider returning only necessary data from PHP

       //In case, data has to processed to extract sub-portions
       //Split data by a separator and then extract the right part by index
       essentialData = data.split(SEPARATOR)[1];

       //Slice your string by index of characters in string
       //essentialData = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

       //Finally append it to the parent div as a child div
       $("#listOfReturns").append("<div>"+essentialData +"</div>")
    });
}
setInterval(sth, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks but same result :(  it returns complete page, but I don't want to use jQuery to put data in, however each time I want to call the function that is in PHP!

Comment: Are you able to see the console logs ticking? Every second?

Comment: YEP I am! Every Second!

Comment: Which means things are working as they should :) I think you forgot to add a `return` within the method call and place this `if($_POST)` at the top of your page.

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: No dear, I added but because it is middle of the page, causes the page not to be loaded completely! and again when I select the text it doesn't deselect it automatically!

Comment: By else is working, you mean `if($_POST["on"])` is evaluating to false and hence ` sthElse();` is not called? Can you try using `isset` as in my edited answer?

Comment: I changed my jQuery code to: $('html').html(''); $('').html(data); and it worked, and the results showed, but it refreshes complete page, however I want small div tag to be refreshed!

Comment: Ok so, Arya, your problem seems to be that you want to see the output on your page.

Comment: So I decided to get the data and use a function to extract the part that I want, could you help me in this please dear Obsidian?

Comment: substr, substring or what? I really appreciate if you tell me which function can be best for :)

Comment: Updated answer with some hints for that.

Comment: Ideally, you should simply return only the data you want from your PHP, for that you should put your `if` block in PHP at the top and use `return` at the end of your `sthElse`. This way you don't have to do the messy string slicing

Comment: yeah, that's right, but as I said because it is in the middle of the page, if I use return, the rest of the page won't be loaded :) anyway thanks dear Obsidian :)

Comment: Ok. Just a thumb-rule, exchange only necessary information. Saves you both the data transfer and the extra computation. Glad your problem's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>

        setInterval(callMe,2000);  

        function callMe (){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test1.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: {on:'1'},
                success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['on']))
        echo '1';
    unset($_POST['on']);
?>
```